# LibGDX - Actors on top of each other, avoid two draw calls

Tags: libgdx

I am writing a card game with multiple cards that will stack up on the unplayed deck, and also on player hands.

Currently I add all 100 card actors to the screen at the start to make it easier so i don't have to manage adding them when they are needed. They all start on top of each other and some get dealt out to players hands, which are also just piles of cards. So in theory with a 5 player game there are only 6 cards visible, the deck and the top off each player's hand.

I'm hoping someone can tell me off a clever method to mean that only 6 draw methods get run on the actors that are visible, or do i have to manage all this myself?

If i do, would you suggest adding the actors only when i need them, or adding them invisible and then setting them visible when i need to?

Or another method?

Comment: I would set them visible/invisible as needed. I think that would be easiest.

Comment: So add them all in advance? There's no clever method for working out of they're actually visible or not?

Comment: Only brute force, which would be more work and more CPU intensive. Unless your cards are perfectly rectangular (no rounded corners). Then you could sort them back to front and draw them with depth testing on. That would eliminate overdraw.

Comment: Also note that it's not the draw calls that incur significant performance penalty. It's batch flushes (only if more than a few dozen) and overdraw (drawing pixels to the screen multiple times because they overlap).

Comment: I think overdraw is what I'm trying to ask about (didn't know the name of it). So what are the common methods for avoiding overdraw? And also how can I count the number of batch flushes I'm incurring.

I can paste some code, but it's pretty big, and I don't know which bits to include. I don't overwrite any draw methods or use my own sprites or anything like that. I do use TextureAtlas and I've packed my images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a lot of computation you could just render the image of the cards 6 times. If a card is being dealt just render a 7th being moved across the screen. This avoids calling the draw method of a large number of objects.

Comment: Yeah this is what i will end up having to do. It just feels a bit clunky

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Just cleaning up my SO history, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If only one card in each pile is visible you could use stacks. 
A stack is like an array where you access the elements from one end and only one at a time. You then only call draw methods on the top card on the stack (peek). Then dispose the top card and make the next card the top (pop).

Some tutorials and examples:

[tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_stack_class.htm)

[princeton.edu](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/44st/Stack.java.html)

Or just google "Java Stack" Its very simple to use.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this (though I didn't know there was an actual Stack class, I was just going to use an arraylist).

I think this is in my opinion the last resort, as I'm hoping that in LibGDX there is something that automatically handles overdraw.

Comment: I was also reading somewhere (but have lost the page now) about Libgdx auto handling draw front to back or something, and it only drawing the front actor even if there are others behind it. Is that happening anyway automatically?

Comment: If you only call a draw method on the top card on a stack, there will be no possibility for overdraw.

Comment: This solution is not really compatible with Scene2d.